# Polymorphism in child class

Tags: c++

My goal is to create a method `use(string)` in the child class which has the same name as in the parent class `use(int)`. But the compiler throws the error below:

> error: no viable conversion from 'int' to 'std::string' (aka 'basic_string')

My code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Parent {
public:
    void use(int val) {
        std::cout << "int: " << val << std::endl;
    }
};

class Child: public Parent {
public:
    void use(string val) {
        std::cout << "str: " << val << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Child c;
    c.use(123);
    return 0;
}
```

Why doesn't the child class inherit the method `use(int)` from the parent class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside `Child` add:

```
using Parent::use;
```

Class member lookup in overload resolution halts when it finds one.  A using statement pulls it down into `Child`.

Comment: Except, then, it's not polymorphism, is it?